# Problemas con RStudio, se reinicia bastante el programa

Tags: rstudio

tengo un problema para usar RStudio desde mi laptop; sucede que a los 2min(después a los 10min o hasta los 14 min de haber reiniciado el programa) que lo uso me aparece el siguiente texto:

> rstudio dejó de funcionar
> buscar una solución en línea y cerrar el programa o
> cerrar el programa

después me aparecen

Versión de la aplicación:   1.4.1106.0

Marca de tiempo de la aplicación:   6025848c

Nombre del módulo con errores:  StackHash_a736

Versión del módulo con errores: 6.1.7601.18247

Marca de tiempo del módulo con errores:   521eaf24

Código de excepción:  c0000374

Desplazamiento de excepción:  00000000000c4102

Versión del sistema operativo:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3

Id. de configuración regional:    2058

Información adicional 1:  a736

Información adicional 2:  a73684f2e362a443ae827ff7d5073c7c

Información adicional 3:  1895

Información adicional 4:  18958c667dd9e033d33b945c423138ca

Me frustra bastante porque no puedo avanzar con mi práctica, ya liberé espacio en mi lap y ni así
ayuda!!! :(

Comment: ¿Has probado desinstalar y volver a instalarlo?, también recuerda que puedes usar la versión "cloud" desde aquí: https://rstudio.cloud/  tiene algunas limitaciones en cuanto al tamaño de memoria de los proyectos, pero para una práctica seguramente alcance.

Comment: que buen tip, utilizaré la versión cloud, no me la sabía. Mil gracias